# get dynamic jQuery table cell value

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a table cell which is dynamically changed to textarea. When user clicked on the cell, it will allow user to input some text:

```
$("#myDataTable tbody tr td:nth-child(4)").click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).prev().prev().text() == "") {
        var text = $(this).text();
        $(this).text('');
        $('<textarea />').appendTo($(this)).val(text).select().blur(function() {
            var newText = $(this).val();
            $(this).parent().text(newText).find('textarea').remove();
        });
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

But when I clicked on the deny button to get those values. They are empty string. In fact, when I looked at the html, there's nothing in those tds'. How do I get those values into an array?

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/meidi/3mm4v3q0/3/)

Comment: simply changing the text content of the corresponding td will not change the data of the object associated with your datatable. Change the data instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never used this plugin but I glanced at their API and came up with this answer. It seems it is because you need to update the `data` of the table. From the plugins API:

https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data()

> Note that when used as a setter, this method sets the data to apply to
>   the table, storing it in the data source array or object for the row,
>   but does not update the table's internal caches of the data (i.e. the
>   search and order cache) until the draw() method is called.

So it seems like you are updating the table directly but the table data is not updated. Without changing too much of your code here is one way to do it. Use the provided API to update the data and ask the API to refresh the table for you.

```
$("#myDataTable tbody tr td:nth-child(4)").click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).prev().prev().text() == "") {
        var text = $(this).text();
        $(this).text('');
        $('<textarea />').appendTo($(this)).val(text).select().blur(function() {
            var newText = $(this).val();
            var parentCell = $(this).parent();             // <-----
            parentCell.find('textarea').remove();          // <-----
            table.cell(parentCell).data(newText).draw();   // <-----
        });
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

The lines I updated have `<-----` next to them. I get the cell element, remove the text area, ask the table API for its internal cell representation, set the data through their API and ask them to refresh the table using their `draw` method.

I didn't dig all the way through their API but there may be a way to simply update the DOM as you were doing and then ask the DataTables API to look at the table and update its internal data. But the above works as well.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3mm4v3q0/4/

Feel free to ask any questions.